# How to get options Pre-Selected in Multi Select Dropdown in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have a form where the user selects multiple domains from multiple type select control, When the user submits the form I save the selected domains in another array and save it in session, So I need that if user return on the form they get options selected of the chosen domain.

HTML Code

```
<select clrSelect multiple name="linkDomain" ngModel class="listBox" required="">
    <option *ngFor="let dom of domainList" [selected]="domain | domainFilter:dom.id" [ngValue]="dom.id">{{dom.domain}}</option>
</select>
```

If I remove `ngModel` from select control then I get options selected but the form validation doesn't work.

PIPE

```
@Pipe({ name: 'domainFilter' })
export class DomainFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(domains: Domain[], compareValue: number) {
        if (!domains || !compareValue) {
            return;
        }
        domains.forEach(domain => {
            if (domain.id === compareValue){
                return true;
            }
        })
        return false;
    }
}
```

domains is an array,

```
domains = [{id: "1", domain: "domain1.com"},{id: "2", domain: "domain2.com"}]
```